# Is "insample" in mlr3tuning resampling can be used when we want to do hyperparameter tuning with the full dataset?

Tags: performance, mlr3

I've been trying to do some tuning hyperparameters for the survival SVM model. I used the AutoTuner function from the mlr3tuning package. I want to do tuning for the whole dataset (No train & test split). I've found the resampling class which is "insample". When I look at the mlr3 dictionary, it said "Uses all observations as training and as test set."

My questions is, Is "insample" in mlr3tuning resampling can be used when we want to do hyperparameter tuning with the full dataset and if it applies, why when I tried to use the hyperparameter to the survivalsvm function from the survivalsvm package, it gives the different output of concordance index?

This is the code I used for hyperparameter tuning

```
veteran<-veteran 
set.seed(1)
task = as_task_surv(x = veteran, time = 'time', event = 'status')
learner = lrn("surv.svm", type = "hybrid", diff.meth = "makediff3",
          gamma.mu = c(0.1, 0.1),kernel = 'rbf_kernel')
search_space = ps(gamma = p_dbl(2^-5, 2^5),mu = p_dbl(2^-5, 2^5))
search_space$trafo = function(x, param_set) {
                     x$gamma.mu = c(x$gamma, x$mu)
                     x$gamma = x$mu = NULL
                     x}
ssvm_at = AutoTuner$new(
          learner = learner,
          resampling = rsmp("insample"),
          search_space =  search_space,
          measure = msr('surv.cindex'),
          terminator = trm('evals', n_evals = 5),
          tuner = tnr('grid_search'))
ssvm_at$train(task)
```

And this is the code that I've been trying using the survivalsvm function from the survivalsvm package

```
survsvm.reg <- survivalsvm(Surv(veteran$time , veteran$status ) ~ .,
                       data = veteran,
                       type = "hybrid", gamma.mu = c(32,32),diff.meth = "makediff3",
                       opt.meth = "quadprog", kernel = "rbf_kernel")
pred.survsvm.reg <- predict(survsvm.reg,veteran)
conindex(pred.survsvm.reg, veteran$time)
```

Comment: So if you want to use all data for training and for evaluating the model, then a insample resampling is indeed what you want. Usually however this is a bad idea because you will overfit to your training data (see any book on machine learning). For the second part of your question it would be helpful to have some code what shows what you are trying to do as otherwise (at least for me) it is hard to help you :)

Comment: Thanks for the first answer, I've updated some code for the second question.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you saying that you're getting different results on the same dataset and for the same hyperparameters?